# Gradients of logistic regression?

Tags: linear-algebra

There two connected questions. I have now spent 6 hours trying to solve this. This problem is optional but it kinda frustrates me that I cannot get it right.

Anyway, for data $\{(\mathbf{x_1}, y_1), (\mathbf{x_2}, y_2), ..., (\mathbf{x_N}, y_N)\} \subseteq (\mathbb{R} \times \{-1,1\})^N$, the gradient is
$$
\nabla_{\mathbf{w}}E(\mathbf{w}) = - \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N{\frac{y_n \mathbf{x_n}}{1+\exp(y_n\mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{x_n})}}
$$

1. Now how can I show that this equals:
   $$
   -\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N { [\frac{y_n+1}{2} - \theta(\mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{x_n})] \mathbf{x_n} }
   $$
   where $\theta(\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x_n}) = \frac{1}{1+\exp(-\mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{x_n})}$?
2. If we changed the labels to 0 and 1(that is, $y = \{0,1\}$), how would you derive the gradient
   $$
   \nabla_{\mathbf{w}}E(\mathbf{w}) = -\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N { [y_n - \theta(\mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{x_n})] \mathbf{x_n} }
   $$
   ?

Your time is very very appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Question 1**

All you need to do is to match the terms of the first sum with those of the second one. This is easier to do by separately studying the case when $y_n=1$ and the case $y_n=-1$.

- If $y_n=1$:
  $${\frac{y_n\mathbf{x_n}}{1+\exp(y_n\mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{x_n})}}={\frac{\mathbf{x_n}}{1+\exp(\mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{x_n})}}=\left[\frac{1+1}{2} - \frac{1}{1+\exp(-\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x})}\right] \mathbf{x_n}=\left[\frac{y_n+1}{2} - \theta(\mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{x_n})\right] \mathbf{x_n}$$
- If $y_n=-1$:
  $${\frac{y_n\mathbf{x_n}}{1+\exp(y_n\mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{x_n})}}=-{\frac{\mathbf{x_n}}{1+\exp(-\mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{x_n})}}=\left[0 - \frac{1}{1+\exp(-\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x})}\right] \mathbf{x_n}=\left[\frac{y_n+1}{2} - \theta(\mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{x_n})\right] \mathbf{x_n}$$

**Question 2**

You might have been confused by the fact that from question 1 and question 2, we use the $y_n$ notation to mean different types of labels. To make it clearer, $y_n\in\{-1,+1\}$ is the label as defined in question 1, and define $z_n\in\{0,1\}$ be the redefined labels.

Notice that by definition
$$z_n=\frac {y_n+1} 2$$
then it's just a matter of plugging this into the result of question 1 to obtain
$$\nabla_{\mathbf{w}}E(\mathbf{w}) = -\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N { \left[z_n - \theta(\mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{x_n})\right] \mathbf{x_n} }$$

Comment: Oh my god, thank you sooo much <3 May you have a blessed day!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Wait, now I actually have a follow-up question: why can we just plug $z_n$ into the result from question 1? I mean, this derivative is derived from a function defined wrt $y_n$ and we don't necessarily know if the loss function wrt $z_n$ would yield the same derivative(where $(y_n+1)/2$ is replaced by $z_n$)?

Comment: The derivative is with respect to vector $\mathbf{w}$. It is just replacing $y_n$ with $z_n$, there is nothing special about it.

Comment: Hmm, but we have that the error function is defined to be $-\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N \theta(y_n \mathbf{w}^T \mathbf{x_n})$ when $y = \pm 1$ which is *not* the case when $y = \{0,1\}$ so the loss functions are not the same and thus it confuses me that we can just plug in another number in the error gradient?

Comment: ... thus it confuses me that we can just plug in another number in the error gradient in the case when $y = \pm 1$ to arrive at the gradient in the case when $y = \{0,1\}$?

Comment: The error function is the same in both cases, it's just expressed with different label parameters. But I assure you it is the same (i.e. its value is the same): In both cases, we penalize a misclassification by adding a  $\theta(y_n\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x_n})=\theta((2z_n-1)\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{x_n})$ term. If you want to convince yourself, write both expressions for the error function and derive the gradient w.r.t. $\mathbf{w}$